# Union and Intersection of Sets $A_{i}$ and $B_{j}$

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose $A_{1},A_{2},A_{3},...................,A_{30}$ are thirty sets each with five elements and

$B_{1},B_{2},.......B_{n}$ are $n$ sets each with three elements. Let $\displaystyle \cup_{i=1}^{30}A_{i} = \cup_{j=1}^{30}B_{j} = S\;,$ Assume that

each element of $S$ belongs to exactly $10$ of $A_{i}$ and to exactly $9$ of $B_{j}$. Then find $n$

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ If $A_{i}\;\forall i\in \left\{1,2,3,........,30\right\}$ Contain $5$ elements,

Then $\displaystyle \cup_{i=1}^{30}$ Contain $30\times 5 = 150$ elements.Similarly If $B_{j}\forall j\in \left\{1,2,3,4,......,n\right\}$ elements,

Then $\displaystyle \cup_{j=1}^{30}$ contain $n\times 3 = 3n$ elements.

Now I did not Understand the meaning of line

$\bf{Assume \; that\;  each\;  element \; of \; S \; belongs\;  to\;  exactly \; 10 \; of \; A_{i} \; and \; to\;  exactly\;  9\;  of \; B_{j}}$.

Help Required, Thanks

Comment: Your statement about the union assumes the sets are disjoint. What if some of the $A_i$ have common elements?

Comment: It seems that it should be "$\cup_{i=1}^{30}A_{i} = \cup_{j=1}^{n}B_{j} = S$" instead of "$\cup_{i=1}^{30}A_{i} = \cup_{j=1}^{30}B_{j} = S$".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Number of sets in equality of union of more than three sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1854876/number-of-sets-in-equality-of-union-of-more-than-three-sets)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since each $A_i$ has $5$ elements, $S=\bigcup A_i$, there are $30$ $A_i$’s, and each element of $S$ belongs to exactly $10$ of $A_i $’s, $|S|=5\cdot 30/10=15$. Similarly, since each $B_j$ has $3$ elements, $S=\bigcup B_j$, there are $n$ $B_j$’s, and each element of $S$ belongs to exactly $9$ of $B_j $’s, $|S|=3\cdot n/9=n/3$. So $15=n/3$ and $n=45$.

Answer (score 0):

> Suppose $A_{1}, A_{2}, \ldots A_{30}$ are thirty sets each with five elements and $B_{1}, B_{2}, \ldots$, $B_n$ are n sets each with three elements. Let $\bigcup_{i=1}^{30} A_{i}=\bigcup_{j=1}^{n} B_{j}=S$. Assume that each element of $S$ belong exactly ten of the $A_{i}^{\prime}$ s and exactly 9 of $B_{j}$ 's. Find $n$.

Since each $A_{i}$ has $5$ elements and each element of $S$ belongs to exactly 10 of $A_{i}^{\prime}$.
$\therefore \quad S=\bigcup_{i=1}^{30} A_{i} \Rightarrow n(S)=\frac{1}{10} \sum_{i=1}^{30} n\left(A_{i}\right)=\frac{1}{10}(5 \times 30)=15$

Again, each $B_{j}$ has 3 elements and each element of $S$ belongs to exactly 9 of $B_{j}$ 's $\therefore \quad S=\bigcup_{j=1}^{n} B_{j} \Rightarrow n(S)=\frac{1}{9} \sum_{j=1}^{n} n\left(B_{j}\right)=\frac{1}{9}(3 n)=\frac{n}{3}$

From (i) and (ii), we get $ 15=\frac{n}{3} \Rightarrow n=45$.