# Number of sets in equality of union of more than three sets

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose $A_{1}$, $A_{2}$, $\dots$, $A_{30}$ are thirty sets each having $5$ elements and $B_{1}$, $B_{2}$, $\dots$, $B_{n}$ are $n$ sets each having $3$ elements. Let $\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{30} A_{i} = \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{n} B_{i} = S$ and each element of S belongs to exactly $10$ of $A_{i}$'s and exactly $9$ of the $B_{j}$'s. Then what is the value of $n$?

I know the formula for union of $3$ sets. If $3$ sets are given with the above condition then I can solve it. Here exactly $10$ of $A_{i}$'s and exactly $9$ of the $B_{j}$'s means each element of $S$ lie in intersection of exactly $10$ of $A_{i}$'s and exactly $9$ of the $B_{j}$'s. Am I right? I don't know how would I handle union of more than $3$ sets.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Union and Intersection of Sets $A_{i}$ and $B_{j}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1316514/union-and-intersection-of-sets-a-i-and-b-j)

Answer (score 1):

Let $s$ be the number of elements in $S.$ You know that
$$30\times5=10\times s$$
and
$$n\times3=9\times s.$$
First solve for $s$ and then solve for $n.$

I get

> $s=15$ and $n=45.$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$A:=\bigcup_{i=1}^{30}A_i\times\{i\}$ has $30\times5=150$ elements.

For $s\in S$ then there are $10$ indices $i\in\{1,\dots,30\}$ such that  $\langle s,i\rangle\in A$.

Conclusion: $S$ has $\frac{150}{10}=15$ elements.

I leave the rest to you.